# Insert/remove rows in NSTableView while keeping a particular row anchored in position

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I'm displaying 2 types of data in an NSTableView, let's call them type A and B. It is a single column and each row is either type A or B. I have 3 buttons which essentially filter the data to display A type rows / B type rows / A&B type rows. Each row is variable height depending on the amount of text.

When the filter button is pressed, I'm loading the new data array and comparing it with the old array and so building up an NSIndexSet of rows which are to be removed or inserted with animation. All good so far.

The challenge is that visually this is disorienting for the user since removal or insertion of rows means that there's no "anchor row" that stays visible.

e.g. Both A&B types of data are shown and rows 7-12 are currently visible in the tableview. Pressing a filter button to only show type A data, causes rows 2/4/5 to be removed but since the scroll position stays the same, the first visible row is now row 10.

By defining an "anchor row" of the first visible row that is present in both the outgoing and incoming data arrays, I can calculate the amount of scroll offset that needs to applied to keep this anchor row in the same position on screen. This works perfectly without row animation but becomes a huge problem when animation is used.

Since there's no direct way to animate the scroll position of an NSTableView, I've tried animating the scrollPoint of the NSClipView (causes the anchor row to jitter since the animations don't exactly sync up) and animating the origin of the NSClipView bounds (doesn't redraw properly during the animation with rows not drawn at all which seems to be a Core Animation conflict with NSTableView).

So my question is whether there is an easier way to do this (subclass of NSTableView?) or am I going to have to abandon NSTableView and make a custom class with NSView subviews?

Comment: What about using `scrollRowToVisible:` once you've calculated the new row location and during the same animation group?

Comment: `scrollRowToVisible` isn't precise enough and doesn't animate.

Comment: I tried various ideas and ended up abandoning animation for anything other than simple insert or removal of single rows.